# jNavigate refresh current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using Jquery [jNavigate](http://jnavigate.com/) plugin and everything works well. Except at some point from  my other part of the JS code I want to be able to refresh content that is currently displayed in the container. How can I achieve this?

Here is what I've done.

I have one container for content that should be displayed via AJAX:

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Then I initialize jNavigate plugin on it

```
$('#container').jNavigate({
        spinner: 'img/loading_icon.gif',
        extTrigger: '.jnav-ext', 
        intTrigger: '.jnav-int'});
```

And I have several links that work with jNavigate:

```
<a href="content/home" class="jnav-ext">Home</a>
<a href="content/about" class="jnav-ext">About</a>
```

So everything works well except I can't refresh current content. Plugin itself has `navigate()` method inside. So how can I call that method from outside to refresh the contents in the container (refresh same page)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out it myself. Here is correct answer:

```
$('#container').jNavigate("navigate", {url: window.location.href});
```

Invoke this from whenever you want to reload current page in `#container` which is initially loaded via jNavigate.